# Why Forest plot is not showing the confidence interval bars?

Tags: r, plot, r-forestplot

Hi I am generating a forest plot by following code. but my visual graph doesnot show the confidence interval on boxes. How can i improve this graphical representation.

```
    mydf <- data.frame(
  Variables=c('Variables','Neuroticism_2','Neuroticism_3','Neuroticism_4'),
  HazardRatio=c(NA,1.109,1.296,1.363),
  HazardLower=c(NA,1.041,1.206,1.274),
  HazardUpper=c(NA,1.182,1.393,1.458),
  Pvalue=c(NA,"0.001","<0.001","<0.001"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

#png('temp.png', width=8, height=4, units='in', res=400)
rowseq <- seq(nrow(mydf),1)
par(mai=c(1,0,0,0))
plot(mydf$HazardRatio, rowseq, pch=15,
     xlim=c(-10,12), ylim=c(0,7),
     xlab='', ylab='', yaxt='n', xaxt='n',
     bty='n')
axis(1, seq(0,5,by=.5), cex.axis=.5)

segments(1,-1,1,6.25, lty=3)
segments(mydf$HazardLower, rowseq, mydf$HazardUpper, rowseq)

text(-8,6.5, "Variables", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t1h <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Variables), mydf$Variables, '')
text(-8,rowseq, t1h, cex=.75, pos=4, font=3)



text(-1,6.5, "Hazard Ratio (95%)", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t3 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$HazardRatio), with(mydf, paste(HazardRatio,' (',HazardLower,'-',HazardUpper,')',sep='')), '')
text(3,rowseq, t3, cex=.75, pos=4)

text(7.5,6.5, "P Value", cex=.75, font=2, pos=4)
t4 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Pvalue), mydf$Pvalue, '')
text(7.5,rowseq, t4, cex=.75, pos=4)

#dev.off()
```

Edit

I even tried to do this by forestplot package. But i am not getting Confidence interval on grpah as well as i want presentation as above graph.

```
test_data <- data.frame(coef=c(1.109,1.296,1.363),
                        low=c(1.041,1.206,1.274),
                        high=c(1.182,1.393,1.458),
                        boxsize=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
row_names <- cbind(c("Variable", "N_Quartile 1", "N_Quartile 2", "N_Quartile 3"),
                   c("HR", test_data$coef), c("CI -95%",  test_data$low), c("CI +95%", test_data$high) )
test_data <- rbind(NA, test_data)
forestplot(labeltext = row_names,
           mean = test_data$coef, upper = test_data$high,
           lower = test_data$low,
             clip =c(0.1, 25),
           is.summary=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
           boxsize = test_data$boxsize,

           zero = 1,colgap = unit(3, "mm"), txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label= gpar(cex = 0.7),
                                                             title = gpar(cex = 1) ),
           xlog = TRUE,
           xlab = "HR (95% CI)",
           col = fpColors(lines="black", box="black"),
                      ci.vertices = TRUE,
           xticks = c(0.1, 1, 2.5,5,7.5))
```

Comment: i don't think it works by just calling plot. you needa use a package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html

Comment: Thanks. But i also tried it with forestplot package. Please check my edit in question for example. But problem still persists. 1) I am not getting confidence interval on graph. 2)I am not happy with graph presentation , the first graph is more detailed. How can i solve my confidence interval problem and getting same visual presentation with forestplot as i got in first plot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @StupidWolf I will be grateful if you give a try to my reproducable example.

Comment: in the first plot, the ci are too small, and they are simply covered by your boxes, ```segments(mydf$HazardLower, rowseq, mydf$HazardUpper, rowseq,col="blue",lwd=3)```

Comment: honestly i suggest using forestplot, don't reinvent the wheel, you can tweak this parameter in forest plot, ```graphwidth=unit(80,'mm')``` so you can see more of your plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intervals are quite small, so if you do it manually on `plot` it will take a while to refine the correct settings, and putting text together with it is not trivial. Right now your first code is not even 50% there.

My suggestion is to build up the plot slowly using forestplot, and identify the problem, for example if you just plot your data.frame, you see it works, that is the c.i is there, just that it's very narrow, and that's your problem at hand, adjusting the size using `lwd.ci` so that it is visible:

```
forestplot(test_data[,1:3],lwd.ci=3)
```

[image]

Now if we add in the text:

```
forestplot(
    labeltext =row_names,
    mean = test_data$coef, upper = test_data$high,
           lower = test_data$low,
    txt_gp=fpTxtGp(cex=0.8),
    is.summary=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
    boxsize = test_data$boxsize,lwd.ci=3)
```

[image]

So the text is taking up a bit too much space, i think one way is to use the conventional est[ll - ul] way of representing estimate and confidence interval, you can see examples [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/metafor/man/forest.default.html). One way I can try below is to wrap the values for the CI into 1 string, and have just two columns for text:

```
library(stringr)

test_data <- data.frame(coef=c(1.109,1.296,1.363),
                        low=c(1.041,1.206,1.274),
                        high=c(1.182,1.393,1.458),
                        boxsize=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1))

column1 = c("Variable", "N_Quartile 1", "N_Quartile 2", "N_Quartile 3")
column2 = cbind(c("HR", test_data$coef), 
           c("CI -95%",  test_data$low),
           c("CI +95%", test_data$high))

L = max(nchar(column2))
padded_text =apply(column2,1,
function(i)paste(str_pad(i,L),collapse=" "))

test_data <- rbind(NA, test_data)

pdf("test.pdf",width=8,height=4)

forestplot(
    labeltext =cbind(column1,padded_text),
    mean = test_data$coef, upper = test_data$high,
           lower = test_data$low,
    txt_gp=fpTxtGp(cex=0.8),align="c",
    is.summary=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
    boxsize = test_data$boxsize,lwd.ci=3,
    graphwidth=unit(100,'mm'))

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Just one question. Reference line should be on "1" in the graph not on " 0" as shown in your graph. Can we fit it to 1?

Comment: include ```zero=1,xticks=c(1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5)```